# How can I get route from url in zf2

Tags: routes, zend-framework2

I need to make redirect after login in zf2
For example come to login page with url
/user/login?redirect=http%3A%2F%site.loc%2Fcategory%test
and I need to get route from url 
maybe some

```
$router->getRouteFromUri($uri);
```

Comment: How about the request class? http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.http.request.html

Comment: @cptnk yes thanks it might help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So as @cptnk said
the best way is

```
        $request = new Request();
        $request->setMethod(Request::METHOD_GET);
        $request->setUri($uri);

        $this->router->match($request);
```

which returns route with params

Answer (score 1):

The request instance can be used to return the request parameters. This can be fetched from within a controller using any of the following.

```
$request = $this->getRequest();
$request = $this->getEvent()->getRequest();
$request = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('request');
```

However, there is already the `Zend\Mvc\Controller\Plugin\Params` that can be used for route or any other request parameters, should you need to access it from the controller.

```
$redirect = $this->params('redirect', false); 
// or
$redirect = $this->params()->fromQuery('redirect', false);
```

If you need to *generate* the URL you can use the URL plugin `Zend\Mvc\Controller\Plugin\Url`.

```
$this->url()->fromRoute(
    $nameOfRoute, // use null for last matched route
    $arrayOfRouteParams,
    $booleanShouldReuseMatchedParams,
    array(
        'query' => array('redirect' => $redirctUrl)
    )
);
```

Where the above is simply a convenience class for manually assembling the URL directly with the router.